# Having positive charge density, yet a particle experiences an attractive force

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, maxwell-equations

Before flagging this as a homework question, note that I'm not asking to solve something. I have the answer but cannot interpret it correctly. I have a conceptual problem that appeared in a specific example in electromagnetism.

I have a charge density like a gaussian distribution $\rho = e^{-r^2}$.

By Maxwell's equation:

$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

Solving it by ignoring the angular parts, so using (setting $\epsilon_0 = 1$):
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r E_r) = e^{-r^2}$$

One of the solutions is:

$$E_r = -\frac{e^{-r^2}}{2r}$$

Such that $E_r$ is the radial part. And the solution indeed has a divergence equal to the charge density.

The problem is that if I graph this field, it points to the origin, even though the charge density is always positive.

This means that if I put a proton, it gets pulled towards the origin even though there is a positive charge density there. May someone clear this up?

Comment: "Before flagging this as a homework question..." What do you mean "flagging it?" This does fall into the category of: "Homework or check-my-work question."

Comment: It's clearly a check-my-work question. It should probably be closed. It's not super helpful on this forum because the problem is that you messed up your own starting points (e.g. definition of div in spherical coordinates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric field indeed cannot point towards the center, because for any positive $a$, net electric field of charge outside the sphere $r = a$ vanishes inside that sphere, and electric field of the charge inside the sphere is repulsive.

You made two mistakes in the derivation.

First, divergence of a radial function in three-dimensional space is not as you have written, but it is

$$
\nabla \cdot (E_r \mathbf e_r ) = \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r (r^2 E_r).
$$

Second, when you remove derivative, you need to allow for general constant in the anti-derivative, which later will be determined from the boundary conditions.

$$
\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r (r^2 E_r) = e^{-r^2}
$$

$$
\partial_r (r^2 E_r) = r^2 e^{-r^2}
$$

$$
r^2 E_r = \int r^2 e^{-r^2} dr 
$$

$$
r^2 E_r = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \text{erf}(r) - \frac{1}{2}re^{-r^2} + C
$$

In this case, since $E_r(0) = 0$ from symmetry, $C=0$ and we get

$$
E_r = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4r^2} \text{erf}(r) - \frac{1}{2r}e^{-r^2}.
$$

Comment: For OP I would like to point out this  formula assumes the distribution takes up all of freespace, unless applying a domain restriction upto a certain r. If you meant that this distribution abruptly stops at a certain point, you need to solve $$\nabla \cdot \vec{E}_{2} = 0 $$ Applying the boundary condition that the field is continuous for both solutions at the point of the domain restriction r=R. $$\vec{E}_{2}(R) = \vec{E}_{2}(R)$$